# How can I track network traffic in chrome devtools while browsing?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The only way I know how to use the network tab in chrome devtools is to open up the network tab first then reload the page I'm interested in.  Many times though I would like to browse a little while on a page to test things.  Any clicks on the page though take me to inspect the html element I clicked.  What am I missing?  Can I leave the inspect mode, continue to browse, while I track files on the network tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.
You can leave the developer tools always open (and even record the requests).

The problem is that you're using the shortcut to inspect; not the Developer Tools shortcut.

**In Windows and Linux use F12.** On Mac, check at the menu.

Comment: when I do this I am in inspect mode and there is no browsing, only inspecting

Comment: how are you opening dev tools?

Comment: are you using right click inspect? or are you using F12 (Windows)?

Comment: I do ctrl + alt+ c on ubuntu

Comment: that's the problem. that is the shortcut for inspection.
go to chrome menu > More tools > Developer tools

Comment: and see the shorcut by the way. (anyway F12 should also work)

Comment: So f12 is a shortcut to devtools if I don't want to go into inspect mode?

Comment: I'm not sure about Ubuntu. but in principle it is also.. 
the best way is to check the shortcut shown in the menu.